# Why button is big?

Tags: android

I have the below layout which contains a button, I'm trying to reduce the size, mainly height, of button, but button height allows stays the same

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:background="#FFDBE2ED"
             android:paddingBottom="0dp"
              android:paddingTop="0dp" >

            <!--Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2px"
                android:height="15dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:width="70dp" >
            </Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:layout_marginRight="3px"
                android:layout_marginTop="2px"
                android:height="0dp"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:width="70dp"
                  >
            </Button>
       </LinearLayout>
```

any idea?

Comment: Maybe because of margins. Is it also wide? Try to skip one of layout_marginTop or marginBottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried your code and button looks fine. What do you want to look it like? Button as small(short) as it defined by current android theme. You have to change button style to custom one, to make spacing inside of the button different to make it shorter.

When you place standard android button  android will use its theme style, including 9-patch image for button background. That image has internal paddings for the text. If you need a different look of the button then you need to create a custom Button control inherited from the Button and overwrite styles.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` which means it will always be as tall as the content inside it.  Try playing around with that value to change the height.

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Instead of using `wrap_content` you can specify a view's width or height using DP (Density Independant Pixels) Try changing `wrap_content` to `50dp` or whatever value that suits your needs.